# How to write multiple txt files in Python?

Tags: python, twitter

I am doing preprocessing tweet in Python. My unpreprocess tweets are in a folder. Each file containing unpreprocess tweet named 1.txt, 2.txt,...10000.txt. I want to preprocess them and write them into new files that also named 1.txt , 2.txt,...10000.txt. 
My code is as follows :

```
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
with open(filename) as file:
    tweet=file.read()
    def processTweet(tweet):
        tweet = tweet.lower()
        tweet = re.sub('((www\.[^\s]+)|(https?://[^\s]+))','URL',tweet)
        tweet = re.sub('@[^\s]+','USER',tweet)
        tweet = re.sub('[\s]+', ' ', tweet)
        tweet = re.sub(r'#([^\s]+)', r'\1', tweet)            
        tweet = tweet.translate(None, string.punctuation)
        tweet = tweet.strip('\'"')
        return tweet

    fp = open(filename)
    line = fp.readline()

    count = 0
    processedTweet = processTweet(line)
    line = fp.readline()
    count += 1
    name = str(count) + ".txt"
    file = open(name, "w")
    file.write(processedTweet)
    file.close()
```

But that code just give me a new file named 1.txt that already preprocessed. How can I write the other 9999 files? Is there any mistake in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your count is getting reset to 0 with the call to count=0. So everytime it is about to write a file, it write "1.txt". Why are you trying to reconstruct the filename, instead of just using the existing filename for the tweet you are preprocessing. Also, you should move your function definition to outside the loop:

```
def processTweet(tweet):
    tweet = tweet.lower()
    tweet = re.sub('((www\.[^\s]+)|(https?://[^\s]+))','URL',tweet)
    tweet = re.sub('@[^\s]+','USER',tweet)
    tweet = re.sub('[\s]+', ' ', tweet)
    tweet = re.sub(r'#([^\s]+)', r'\1', tweet)            
    tweet = tweet.translate(None, string.punctuation)
    tweet = tweet.strip('\'"')
    return tweet

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
  with open(filename) as file:
    tweet=file.read()

  processedTweet = processTweet(tweet)

  file = open(filename, "w")
  file.write(processedTweet)
  file.close()
```

Comment: thank you so much, it works now :D
another question, can I store the results into single csv file instead of multiple txt files? which part of the code that should change?

Comment: You would need to change the part of the code that writes to the file. Instead of reusing the same filename and overwriting each text file, you would just specify a single output.csv file to write to, and open the file in append mode: `file = open("output.csv", "a+")`
Then, when you write the processedTweet out, you need to add a trailing comma: `file.write("{},".format(processedTweet))`

Comment: yes,it works, but the output is not the way I wanted. It prints 10000 columns. How can we make it into 10000 rows instead of 10000 columns?

Comment: oh I solved it. Just add '\n' in 'file.write("{},\n".format(processedTweet))' right? Thank you so much @louahola for your help.